# Empty input field issue

Tags: javascript, html, meteor

I have an event handler that packages up the contents of an input box and persists it to the user's collection:

```
'click #update_username': function(ev, template){
    ev.preventDefault();

    var username_field = template.$('input[id="username_field"]').val();

    console.log(username_field);

    Meteor.call('updateUsername', this._id, username_field);

}
```

Each template instance is rendered to the browser like this:

http://jsfiddle.net/dc6n1k5s/

My issue is that the `username_field` variable that I use to send the update to the server is only defined for *the first instance of the template in the browser*.

Thus, if I am trying to edit the username of the second (or third...) entry on the page, my variable thinks the input field is empty (or it thinks its the value of the first instance of that input field on the page), because technically the first input box on the page with id='username_field' is empty.

How do I get around this?

**EDIT**

The input boxes are only shown when the user clicks 'edit' button.  Otherwise, they have `display: none`.

Comment: IDs have to be unique, there can only be one field with `id=username_field`.

Comment: If you're using a template to make repeated elements, you should use classes, not IDs, to identify the fields. Then when you click on something, you can use `$(this)` to get the clicked element, and use jQuery navigation functions like `.closest()` and `.find()` to find the related elements.

Comment: If you have multiple elements named the same you'll have to do some domain traversing to find a specific, otherwise you get the first instance. You'll have to traverse the DOM and find that field relative to your update element, unless you pass some data attributes with the element to help you find it. I would use `event.currentTarget` then find `.closest('.username_field`).val();` (changed to class, see above comments)